# Which mysql timeout do I must modify?

Tags: java, android, mysql, glassfish, raspberry-pi

I've set up on my Raspberry Pi a Glassfish server (4) and a MySQL, to launch my webservices for my Android Application.
Everything is okay after a lot of problems !
But one question stay in my mind for me, why every day I'm trying to execute a query with my app, I must restart my glassfish to have a result (I have a 500 Internal Server Error).

I've searched on the net, and I think it's a timeout from MySQL, who close the connection between him and Glassfish, so I want to know what I must doing to solve this problem ?

Thanks by advance !

**EDIT**

Stack Trace :

```
example.webservices.exceptions.ServiceException: L'appel au webservice a rencontré une erreur 500 : could not execute query
  at example.webservices.accessservice.UserAccessService.isUserExists(UserAccessService.java:52)
  at example.androidapp.asynctasks.VerifyUserTask.doInBackground(VerifyUserTask.java:38)
  at example.androidapp.asynctasks.VerifyUserTask.doInBackground(VerifyUserTask.java:20)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the MySql log output (/var/log/mysql/mysql.err) ?

Comment: "I have a 500 Internal Server Error". Which has a logged cause. What is it?